# Basics to create a uploader service Software

Tags: html, uploader

i'm using a web page called wcm7.com to upload my pc backups files, but i'm thinking about create a software uploader for my computer to make it more easy.

The question is, ¿What I need to know to comunicate my software with the website and do the uploads/downloads directly from the program, without going to the website everytime?

I invested the code and it uses this code to upload, maybe it can help:

```
<div id="upload" class="button" original-title="Upload max. 5 GB">
            <form data-upload-id="1" id="data-upload-form" class="file_upload_form" action="http://space.wcm7.com/index.php/apps/files/ajax/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="file_upload_target_1">
                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" id="max_upload" value="1235257" original-title="">
                <!-- Send the requesttoken, this is needed for older IE versions
                     because they don't send the CSRF token via HTTP header in this case -->
                <input type="hidden" name="requesttoken" value="3c3c3c4fad5gh" id="requesttoken" original-title="">
                <input type="hidden" class="max_human_file_size" value="(max 5 GB)" original-title="">
                <input type="hidden" name="dir" value="/" id="dir" original-title="">
                <input type="file" id="file_upload_start" name="files[]" original-title="" multiple="multiple">
                <a href="http://space.wcm7.com/#" class="svg"></a>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a little script for the [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) browser, either via selenium or another binding. The script could log in for you and upload whatever file you want. See the tutorials for specifics or ask here again if you get stuck. There are bindings for many programming languages, if you decide to use [ghostdirver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) (webdriver version of phantomjs).

P.S. i hope you strongly encrypt your backups before uploading them into the cloud!

Comment: Thank you, i'm thinking to do it with java like jdownloader. To have the option to share the program on the future.

Comment: you are welcome. as said, if you get stuck just ask again here with specific questions about the technology.